# How do I fix this IOError: [Errno socket error] [Errno 11004]?

Tags: python, python-3.x, urllib, ioerror

This simple **Python 3** script:

```
import urllib.request

host = "scholar.google.com"
link = "/scholar.bib?q=info:K7uZdMSvdQ0J:scholar.google.com/&output=citation&hl=en&as_sdt=1,14&ct=citation&cd=0"
url = "http://" + host + link
filename = "cite0.bib"
print(url)
urllib.request.urlretrieve("http://scholar.google.com" + url, filename)
```

raises this exception:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/ricardo/Desktop/Google-Scholar/BibTex/test2.py", line 8, in <module>
    urllib.request.urlretrieve("http://scholar.google.com" + url, filename)
  File "C:\Python32\lib\urllib\request.py", line 150, in urlretrieve
    return _urlopener.retrieve(url, filename, reporthook, data)
  File "C:\Python32\lib\urllib\request.py", line 1569, in retrieve
    fp = self.open(url, data)
  File "C:\Python32\lib\urllib\request.py", line 1541, in open
    raise IOError('socket error', msg).with_traceback(sys.exc_info()[2])
  File "C:\Python32\lib\urllib\request.py", line 1537, in open
    return getattr(self, name)(url)
  File "C:\Python32\lib\urllib\request.py", line 1715, in open_http
    return self._open_generic_http(http.client.HTTPConnection, url, data)
  File "C:\Python32\lib\urllib\request.py", line 1695, in _open_generic_http
    http_conn.request("GET", selector, headers=headers)
  File "C:\Python32\lib\http\client.py", line 967, in request
    self._send_request(method, url, body, headers)
  File "C:\Python32\lib\http\client.py", line 1005, in _send_request
    self.endheaders(body)
  File "C:\Python32\lib\http\client.py", line 963, in endheaders
    self._send_output(message_body)
  File "C:\Python32\lib\http\client.py", line 808, in _send_output
    self.send(msg)
  File "C:\Python32\lib\http\client.py", line 746, in send
    self.connect()
  File "C:\Python32\lib\http\client.py", line 724, in connect
    self.timeout, self.source_address)
  File "C:\Python32\lib\socket.py", line 386, in create_connection
    for res in getaddrinfo(host, port, 0, SOCK_STREAM):
IOError: [Errno socket error] [Errno 11004] getaddrinfo failed
```

I can open the url that results from the `print` statement just fine:

> http://scholar.google.com/scholar.bib?q=info:K7uZdMSvdQ0J:scholar.google.com/&output=citation&hl=en&as_sdt=1,14&ct=citation&cd=0

What is causing this? I tried changing `http://` to `http:///` (three slashes), but the same exception is raised.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's your problem:

```
urllib.request.urlretrieve("http://scholar.google.com" + url, filename)
```

You're adding the `http://scholar.google.com` part twice (`url` *already* starts `http://scholar.google.com`). Therefore `urillib` thinks you're asking for a page on `scholar.google.comhttp` -- needless to say, this domain does not exist. Which is exactly what your error says.

Just request `url` obviously.

Handy hint to find this kind of thing faster in the future: when adding a `print` statement for debugging, be sure to print the *actual value you are using in the command you're debugging.* You would have found this in approximately two seconds if your `print` statement had *also* concatenated the base URL.

Comment: That fixes the `IOError`, but now I get a `ValueError: read of closed file` error. I should post a new question, I take it? All I changed was removing the string concatenation.

Comment: Yeah, that's a different problem entirely.