# IOError: [Errno socket error] [Errno 11004] getaddrinfo failed when I'm trying to open a url

Tags: python, urllib

I'm trying to web scrape using Python at me new job using the same method I used at my previous 2 jobs except it's not working now. Here's the code-

```
import urllib
from urllib import urlopen
url = 'http://www.google.com'
html = urllib.urlopen(url).read()
```

And the error is this-

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#3>", line 1, in <module>
    html = urllib.urlopen(url).read()
  File "C:\Users\NREARDO2\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda2\lib\urllib.py", line 87, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url)
  File "C:\Users\NREARDO2\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda2\lib\urllib.py", line 213, in open
    return getattr(self, name)(url)
  File "C:\Users\NREARDO2\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda2\lib\urllib.py", line 350, in open_http
    h.endheaders(data)
  File "C:\Users\NREARDO2\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda2\lib\httplib.py", line 1053, in endheaders
    self._send_output(message_body)
  File "C:\Users\NREARDO2\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda2\lib\httplib.py", line 897, in _send_output
    self.send(msg)
  File "C:\Users\NREARDO2\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda2\lib\httplib.py", line 859, in send
    self.connect()
  File "C:\Users\NREARDO2\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda2\lib\httplib.py", line 836, in connect
    self.timeout, self.source_address)
  File "C:\Users\NREARDO2\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda2\lib\socket.py", line 557, in create_connection
    for res in getaddrinfo(host, port, 0, SOCK_STREAM):
IOError: [Errno socket error] [Errno 11004] getaddrinfo failed
```

Is this because I'm working at a conglomerate and there's a security protocol preventing me from doing this or is there another way to get around it?

Comment: Refer below thread - You need to pass proxy attribute
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7334199/getaddrinfo-failed-what-does-that-mean/48788583#48788583

Answer (score 0):

According to [Windows Sockets Error Codes - MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740668(v=vs.85).aspx), error 11004 means:

> WSANO_DATA 11004
>
> Valid name, no data record of requested type.
>
> The requested name is valid and was found in the database, but it does not have the correct associated data being resolved for. The
>   usual example for this is a host name-to-address translation attempt
>   (using `gethostbyname` or `WSAAsyncGetHostByName`) which uses the DNS
>   (Domain Name Server). An MX record is returned but no A
>   record—indicating the host itself exists, but is not directly
>   reachable.

In human terms, this means that **your host name** (as extracted from the URL) **is valid format-wise but cannot be resolved to a valid IP.**

In other questions ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6180720/how-to-fix-socket-gaierror-11004-getaddrinfo-failed-error-in-gae),[2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23542107/socket-gaierror-errno-11004-getaddrinfo-failed),[3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9054386/ioerror-errno-socket-error-errno-11004-getaddrinfo-failed),[4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7334199/getaddrinfo-failed-what-does-that-mean),[5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11531275/how-do-i-fix-this-ioerror-errno-socket-error-errno-11004)), people report having this problem if they:

- have the name mapped to an invalid IP (like `0.0.0.0`) in their `hosts` file
- format URL incorrectly (like forgetting the third slash in `file:///` or mistyping an IP)
- use an unresolvable DNS name
- have `http_proxy` environment variable or registry [proxy settings](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib.html?highlight=http_proxy#index-2) pointing to a nonexisting host (if there are other problems with proxy settings or the proxy, they would result in another error, not this one)

---

In your case, 2) (and likely 4), too) is out of question, so check the others: if you can [resolve the name with `nslookup`](https://blog.thesysadmins.co.uk/nslookup-common-usage-examples.html) and [if it's present in `hosts`](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/27350/beginner-geek-how-to-edit-your-hosts-file/).

Comment: I'm not following what you're saying here. Can you provide me with some code or a procedure to determine how to work around this?

Comment: Hi is telling you: Check your nameserver. It looks like you are hitting a configuration issue on your box. E.g. by running nslookup from inside cmd to google

Comment: @NickReardon I added some howto links, read up on those things for more info. The gist is: the problem is external to your code and can very well result from your machine and/or corporate network configuration. You can diagnose it as suggested to find out what specifically is wrong and what you can do about it.